# "Through difficult to defeat"

Tags: meaning, popular-refrains

There is a saying that when translated from my language is *Through difficult to defeat*. Is it correct to say it this way? I know that the correct saying is *To stars through difficulties*.

It is very important for me to know as I need to use it for a tattoo.

Comment: If you can mention the original saying in your language, it can help us help you.

Comment: I think you might be better off getting the tattoo done in your native language, rather than hoping we can get this saying right. I'm not sure what your saying is trying to convey.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of the phrase "Per ardua ad astra"?  This is Latin, not English.

Comment: I believe you are trying to say "Through difficulty to defeat" though I do not know enough English grammar to know if its grammatically correct.

Comment: Considering the OP's rep of 1, down votes may not be warranted yet. Just my 2c.

Comment: Hi! This is bit difficult to explain in English, but the meaning is that you have had hard times and now you are over them. Language are in Finnish and saying ''Vaikeuksien kautta voittoon'' (=Through difficulties to defeat). I know that there is one song called the same. Origin of pharse is latin ''Per ardua ad astra''. I hope this help a bit explaining what I mean.

Comment: Matti - the translation of *voittoon*, I think, should be *to victory*, not *defeat*, which is the opposite. So "Through difficulties to victory".

Comment: Note that mottos of this kind normally speak of aspirations, not achievements. So not "I have had hard times and am over them", but "hard times are ahead but I will get through them".

Comment: Yes I think that is the correct translate but I like more ''defeat'' so that is why I needed to know about this. But maybe I will consider''Per ardua ad astra'' or ''Through difficulties to victory'' as a tattoo idea. I am not sure about the Finnish ''Vaikeuksien kautta voittoon'' as a tattoo in my skin. Thank you all for the help and now I am bit more wise! :)

Comment: "Through difficulties to victory" would be "Per ardua ad victoria".

Comment: Thank you slim! I think that one sounds better than ad astra. I might choose that one :)! (It also look good). If you guys have any other ideas related this tattoo idea, I would glad to hear them!

Comment: What's wrong with using the original phrase in your native language? Is there something to gain by translating to a language you understand less?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that but because I like more the sound and look of English and Latin version. Like I said I will consider the Finnish version also. That is a good question but I think I already answered that in this message.

Answer (score 5):

"To *the* stars through difficulties" is an English translation of the Latin motto "*Ad astra per aspera*".

As you can see, the Latin phrase is rather nicely formed; short and alliterative. The English translation is not very poetic.

It is the motto of many institutions, including the US state of Kansas, NASA and many countries' air forces.

In it

- "astra"; "the stars" signifies aspirations, glory, better things. Of course when used by NASA and air forces, is is slightly more literal.
- "aspera"; "difficulty", "hardships", meaning problems we pass through on the way

Like many mottos, it is not really a full sentence in English. There is an implied extra part:

> (I/we aim to get) to the stars through difficulties

"Through difficult to defeat" is not correct.

If you mean "(I aim to) tolerate hardships in order to eventually defeat (something)" then the following are acceptable English sentences:

- Through difficulties to victory
- Through difficulty to victory
- Through hardships to victory
- Through hardship to victory

However none of them are well known phrases.

Be careful with "defeat".

- "Joshua led his army to defeat the Egyptians" - means Joshua won (defeat is a verb)
- "Napoleon led his army to defeat" - means Napoleon lost (defeat is a noun)

Answer (score 5):

The Finnish saying  "vaikeuksien kautta voittoon" has been [translated directly](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Finnish_proverbs#V) as:

> - *"Vaikeuksien kautta voittoon."*
>
>   - Translation: "Through difficulties into victory."
>   - Notes: A Finnish form for the Latin adage "Per aspera ad astra."

It has also been [translated](http://www.trueknowledge.com/q/what_does_%22vaikeuksien_kautta_voittoon%22_mean_in_finnish) [elsewhere](http://www.sanakirja.org/search.php?id=3142510&l2=3) into the well known English expression:

> No pain, no gain

Answer (score 3):

It's the motto of the British Royal Air Force  which, in Latin, is *Per Ardua ad Astra* ('Through hardship to the stars'). It means that by overcoming difficulties we can achieve our aims.

Comment: However, *defeat* and *stars* do not seem to agree in any manner. OP mentions *defeat* in the original and *stars* in a probable English analogue.

Comment: I think Matti meant he has defeated his troubles, rather than he has experienced defeat.

Answer (score 2):

wiktionary: [vaikeuksien kautta voittoon](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vaikeuksien_kautta_voittoon)

Proverb

vaikeuksien kautta voittoon

1. **no pain, no gain**.

Answer (score 0):

A less concise English Language alternative might be, "If you're going through Hell, keep going." A similar phrase was made into a [song](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_You%27re_Going_Through_Hell_%28Before_the_Devil_Even_Knows%29).

Answer (score 0):

There's also Nietzsche's famous line 'What does not kill me, makes me stronger' (from a man notoriously enfeebled by illness!)